# Oracle APEX 18.1 Line charts not working as expected

Tags: oracle, charts, line, oracle-apex

I am creating Line chart in Oracle Apex 18.1 with Jets. I tested sql query in  Sample charts and its working fine.

```
select to_char(to_date(t2.M_DATE, 'DD-MON-YY'),'IW') week1, round(avg(t1.my_data),0) md 
from m_table t1 
JOIN M_TABLE_MASTER t2 
ON t1.b_no = t2.b_no
where t2.M_DATE >'01-JAN-19' 
group by to_char(to_date(t2.M_DATE, 'DD-MON-YY'),'IW') 
order by week1;
```

And it is plotting 28 points from my database.

However when I am creating charts in my APP, the above same query plotting 52 points.